# How to request and send payments via Gmail API and Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace

I want to request and send payments via Gmail API and Google Apps Script.

[Here is documentation for using Google Apps Script with the Gmail API.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)

[Here is information on how to manually request and send payments using Gmail.](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644136)

[Here is information for developers on how to use Google Pay.](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/)

So, based on that, there seems like there should be a way to use Google Apps Script to tap into the Gmail API to send and receive payments. But I can't find any documentation how to do that.

So how can I accomplish that?

[Code.gs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app.html#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

```
// Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
});
```

Comment: Checked the Gmail API; there are no endpoints that support this feature. Its only available via Gmail's user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API or Apps Script service available for that use-case.

You should go to the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and submit a feature request for this.