# How to integrate Stripe payments with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, stripe-payments

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606040), Gmail does not expose an API for sending and receiving payments. Therefore, [I am trying to use Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) to accomplish that.

Code.js

```js
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

(async () => {
  const product = await stripe.products.create({
    name: 'My SaaS Platform',
    type: 'service',
  });
})();
```

However, GAS does not directly support `async` and `require` at this time. Is there any possible workaround so I can use Stripe to send and receive payments in my GAS app?

If that's not possible, what direction should I go from here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, the module of Node.js cannot be directly used for Google Apps Script. So it is required to prepare the script for Google Apps Script. Fortunately, at [the official document of the link](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart) in your question, there are several samples. Using this, how about converting to the script of Google Apps Script?

### Sample script:

When your script in your question is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

(async () => {
  const product = await stripe.products.create({
    name: 'My SaaS Platform',
    type: 'service',
  });
})();
```

#### To

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/products";
  var params = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc:")},
    payload: {name: "My SaaS Platform", type: "service"}
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- In this case, both requests of Node.js and Google Apps Script are the same.

### Note:

- At the sample script of Node.js, `sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc` is used for the key. But in this case, because the basic authorization is used, please use `sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc:` by adding `:`.

### References:

- [Billing Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Mowzer Thank you for replying and testing the script. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63013143/1640892

Comment: @Let Me Tink About It I checked it and proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It doesn't feel very safe to me at all to have your secret API key(that can be used to for example refund all your payments or charge your customers) in this script — that should be securely stored on a backend server.

Comment: Google Apps Script = backend. Be careful though not to share the script or spreadsheet when it's a container-bound apps script.