# How to get "balance transactions" from Stripe API via UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the transaction details from Stripe API "The balance transaction object" with a Google Apps Script app. I have studied another question to get my code:

[How to integrate Stripe payments with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635015/how-to-integrate-stripe-payments-with-google-apps-script)

And I have read the following Strip documentation:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions

My code is:

```
function callStripe() {
  var url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions";

  var params = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_XXX:")},
    payload: {id: "txn_1GryACFHk3f0sLjYo9FDDSM1", source: "ch_1GryABFHk3f0sLjY88wmWPFy"}
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

When I ran the function, I got the following error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.stripe.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: { "error": { "message": "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/balance_transactions). Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at http... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 59, file "Stripe")

Line 59 is referring to the `var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);`

Comment: Why are you sending a payload when trying to do a GET request?

Comment: Oh thats the different, it works after i delete the payload. Sorry I am a new learner of coding, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, I've added this info as an answer - `UrlFetchApp` assumes you wanted to make a POST request since you added a `payload`, therefore the actual request is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Stripe API request returns the following error message and `404` HTTP code:

> "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/balance_transactions)"

**Solution**

Remove the `payload` parameter from advanced `fetch()` method options. GET requests cannot have a body (which is what `payload` parameter represents), but `UrlFetchApp` assumes that if the payload is provided then the developer actually attempts to make a POST request and changes the method accordingly.

**Reference**

1. Stripe API [reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions)
2. GET method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)
3. POST method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)
4. `fetch()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)