# Send Invoice to Email Stripe (Google App Scir

Tags: google-apps-script, stripes, stripe-payments

Hi guys I am having trouble sending an invoice due to

> parameter_invalid_integer

this error.

Here's my code of sending

```
var url3 = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices";
      var params3 = {
      method: "post",
      headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sk_test_XXXXX:")},
      payload: 
      {
        customer: responseValue.id,
        collection_method : "send_invoice",
        due_date:responseValue2.date
      }
    };
    var res3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url3, params3);
    Logger.log(res3.getContentText());
```

the due_date is the problem because I can't give its format . The documentation didn't provide any of that or I am just dumb that I can't understand it.

I tried

```
due_date:Date.now()
due_date:"01/01/2022" // tried different formats
```

What I am trying to do is that I am trying to send the invoice base on the email address provided on the invoice.

Please enlighten me . Thank you.

#TRIED 1

```
var timeStamp = (new Date('2022-01-01').getTime())/1000;
due_date = timeStamp
```

still the same error

Comment: Does this help?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013143/converting-stripe-api-syntax-to-google-apps-script

Comment: it doesn't have the date format sir . @MetaMan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it .
What I did was

```
var timeStamp = (new Date('2021-08-10').getTime())/1000;
due_date: ""+timeStamp+""
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

All dates/timestamps in the Stripe API use unix seconds (not milliseconds). So you set the due date to Jan 1 2022 (at 0h UTC, say), you'd use `due_date=1641013200`

Comment: tried that already sir but still got the same error

Comment: Did you notice that TheMaster suggested that you stringify the payload?

Comment: @MetaMan can you explain a bit more sir .

Comment: The timestamp needs to be sent as an integer, not a string. It's possible that your request library is inadvertently converting the parameter to a string. Ensure that your request is encoded using as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` noted at the start of the API ref here: https://stripe.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

```
payload:JSON.stringify({customer:responseValue.id,collection_method:"send_invoice",due_date:responseValue2.date});
```

I don't know for a fact that this will work but I'd try it if TheMaster said to try it.

Comment: actually the only problem is that the `due_date` part is not working because of some kind of format